# button refresh page on postback?

Tags: .net, events, button, click, refresh

I have pretty simple code with Button and onclick event for now.

The problem is that clicking the button causes page reloading and doesn't fire actions defined in the click event.

here's is my code:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkContact" CssClass="panel-login" runat="server">
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text=" Update " CssClass="button" runat="server" />
```

and the event:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnUpdate.Click += new EventHandler(btnUpdate_Click);
}
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("a" + chkContact.Items.Count.ToString());
}
```

It's very strange. I have done it many times and never had problem with button before.

Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the onclick event:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text=" Update " CssClass="button" runat="server" onclick="btnupdate_Click"/>
```

Comment: Hi @sam, I did try with onclick event too, it didn't change anything. I have found the probem, my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any validation controls on the page? If these don't belong to a specific validation group then any post back will fire them.

Answer (score 0):

I have found what caused the problem.
I had a LinkButton below Update button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" Text="Back / Cancel" runat="server" />
```

When I assigned postbackurl to the linkbutton it caused the page reload even if I was clicking Update button not LinkButton.

Very strange, it didn't help adding AutoPostBack="false" to Update and LinkButton so I need to change LinkButton to something else I suppose.